# Convert 16-bit Unicode hex string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, unicode

My websocket app gets string inputs from other sources that only operate with 16-bit Unicode (wchar_t) strings.  Before sending, the strings get encoded as hex with an example of the word 'HELLO' shown here:

```
680065006C006C006F00
```

How can I convert that hex string into a valid Javascript string?  The closest I found was a Node.js example here ([UTF-16 Hex Decode NodeJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61492497/utf-16-hex-decode-nodejs)) but I'm not using Node.js so that doesn't work.

If all the strings were only English then it'd be easy by just skipping each '00' hex digit but again, I need to support all languages and I'm unsure on how to construct a character from two bytes.

Comment: I'm away from my PC at the moment, but you could probably split the string into byte pairs, feed them to `parseInt(bytepair, 16)` and then feed that into [`fromCodePoint()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCodePoint).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `String.prototype.substr()` is a non-standard method, you should avoid its use like in the following example:

```
const str = "680065006C006C006F00", strLen = str.length;
let decoded = "";
for (const i = 0; i < strLen; i+=4) {
    let c = parseInt(str[i+2] + str[i+3] + str[i] + str[i+1], 16)
    decoded += String.fromCodePoint(c);
}
```

Although I would define some functions to handle it instead:

```
const decodeUTF16BytePair = (p) => String.fromCodePoint(parseInt(p[2]+p[3]+p[0]+p[1], 16));

const decodeUTF16ByteString = (str) => {
  let decoded = "", strLen = str.length;
  if (strLen % 4 != 0) {
    throw new Error("Unexpected byte string length");
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < strLen; i+=4) {
    decoded += decodeUTF16BytePair(str.slice(i, i+4));
  }
  return decoded;
}
```

Because `String.fromCodePoint()` can coerce it's argument to a number, we could also use:

```
const decodeUTF16ByteString = (str) => {
  let decoded = "", strLen = str.length;
  if (strLen % 4 != 0) {
    throw new Error("Unexpected byte string length");
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < strLen; i+=4) {
    decoded += String.fromCodePoint("0x"+str[i+2]+str[i+3]+str[i]+str[i+1]);
  }
  return decoded;
}
```

Importantly, with the approach as above, you are switching the endianness of the input bytes but some platforms may not need this inversion.

#### Live Example

```js
const decodeUTF16ByteString = (str) => {
  let decoded = "", strLen = str.length;
  if (strLen % 4 != 0) {
    throw new Error("Unexpected byte string length");
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < strLen; i+=4) {
    decoded += String.fromCodePoint("0x"+str[i+2]+str[i+3]+str[i]+str[i+1]);
  }
  return decoded;
}

const input = "680065006C006C006F00";
const output = decodeUTF16ByteString(input)
  
console.log({ input, output });
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @samthecodingman.  `fromCodePoint` was what I was looking for.  Also need to swap the byte order but this seems to work.

```
for (var i = 0; i < strLen; i+=4) {
    c = parseInt(str.substr(i+2,2) + str.substr(i,2), 16)
    s = s + String.fromCodePoint(c);
}
```